# Append formatted string to string in C without pointer arithmetic

Tags: c, string, append, string-formatting

I wrote a very simple C function to illustrate what I would like to simplify:

```c
void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *me = "Foo";
    char *you = "Bar";
    char us[100];
    memset(us, 100, 0x00);

    sprintf(us, "You: %s\n", you);
    sprintf(us + strlen(us), "Me: %s\n", me);
    sprintf(us + strlen(us), "We are %s and %s!\n", me, you);
    printf(us);
}
```

Is there a standard library function to handle what I'm doing with `sprintf` and advancing the pointer?

Comment: "it seems like there should be a standard library function", the c stdlib is not as extensive as in other language like Java say :) so so I doubt there is

Comment: @hhafez, Spot on; making the transition back to thinking in C (vs. Python and Java) is exactly where I'm at.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`sprintf` returns the number of non-NUL characters written.

```
int len = 0;
len += sprintf(us+len, ...);
len += sprintf(us+len, ...);
...
```

Comment: Ha, I guess that is a bit more brief, but still accomplishing the same way.

Comment: No.  Your example calls strlen() for every iteration, which makes it O(N^2) in the number of sprintf() calls.  This takes advantage of the fact that the printf family of functions return the number of characters printed to get the strlen result for free.  This is, in fact, the standard idiom for this sort of thing.  And as always: make sure you're testing your buffer length and using snprintf if this is anything that will handle untrusted data!

Answer (score 3):

```
char *me="Foo";
char *you="Bar";
char us[100];

char* out = us;
out += sprintf(out,"You: %s\n",you);
out += sprintf(out,"Me: %s\n",me);
out += sprintf(out,"We are %s and %s!\n",me,you);
printf("%s", us);
```

Comment: Please don't `printf(us)`: `printf("%s", us)` and `fputs(us, stdout)` are much safer.

Comment: Not germane to the question, sprintf() is evil too.  Updated, thanks.

Comment: `sprintf` is fine as long when you're confident in the size of your buffers.  On the other hand, `printf(us)` spends extra work scanning for `%` even when it's safe and there shouldn't be any.

Answer (score 3):

You could just use something like this:

```
sprintf(us, "You: %s\nMe: %s\nWe are %s and %s!\n", you, me, me, you);
```

Comment: or for SUS-compliant systems: `sprintf(us, "You: %1$s\nMe: %2$s\nWe are %2$s and %1$s!\n", you, me);`

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for [strcat](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcat/) (or even better [strncat](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strncat/)).

Comment: Format it first, then do the concatenation.

Comment: @AJ, no, you can use the same buffer, just keep catting onto the end of it (although, this is a little inefficient, because each time you invoke `strcat`/`strncat` it needs to rescan the entire string again).

Answer (score 1):

Never use a non-constant string as the first argument to `printf` (or second argument to `fprintf`. This is bad practice. Try changing the `me` variable to `"Muahaha %n%d%n%d%n%d%n%d%n"` and say goodbye to your stack and say hello to `SEGFAULT`. `printf` will try and format the string but you haven't provided any arguments for it to deal with, and even though there are format specifiers in the string `printf` has no idea that you haven't given it any arguments.

If you want to output a 'pre-formatted' string, use `fputs(str,stdout)`. There is rarely a case to use `printf` with a non-constant format string.

Comment: @hhafez, no, dreamlax is saying that using a string other than a literal is dangerous, because it could contain format specifiers you haven't passed arguments for, invoking undefined behavior.  This is a bigger concern when dealing with user input, because it opens you to attacks (never call printf(str) on user input) but also a problem if your program generates the wrong format string.

Comment: @hhafez: `printf` is used to print a formatted string **based on a format description string and supplied arguments**. When you provide a pre-formatted string and no arguments, you aren't using `printf` correctly. When you want to output a string verbatim, use a function dedicated for that purpose, such as `fputs`. If you use `printf` to output non-constant pre-formatted strings, you run the risk of telling `printf` to format parts of the string again. A malicious user can provide format specifiers as input (such as `%n` and `%d`) and your application would most certainly crash.