# How do I add a printf for an eventful happenstance?

Tags: c

Obviously, I need to explain what I mean, as I don't really know how to describe the scenario in so few words. I'm attempting to make a program that takes in a string and a pattern and then tells the user at what offset the pattern was found in the string and how many times. The part I'm stuck on is when the pattern appears more than once, it only outputs the last offset it appears at

```
if(is_equal == 1)   //If string and pattern element are the same, Then declare at which offset
        {
            count++;
            if(count == 1)
            {
                sprintf(offset, "The pattern was found at offset %d", i);   //Prints the offset of the where the pattern appears in the string
                snprintf(full_message, sizeof full_message, "%s", offset);  //Redirects full_message to a buffer
            }
            else
            {
                sprintf(offset, " and %d", i);  //Repeats for every other instance of the pattern
                snprintf(full_message, sizeof full_message, "%s%s", full_message, offset);
            }
        }
```

This is what output looks like if I only have one pattern

```
aerialsong@ubuntu:~$ ./m4p1
Please enter a number: 1234567890
Please enter a pattern: 34
The pattern was found at offset 2
The pattern was found 1 times
```

But if there happens to be more than one:

```
Please enter a number: 123567123678
Please enter a pattern: 123
 and 6
The pattern was found 2 times
```

What is the problem here? By the way, I am unable to use any library besides stdio.h. So does that mean that strcat is off the table?

Comment: You overwrite the `full_message` variable instead of appending to it.

Comment: Use `strcat()` to append to a string.

Comment: [Append Formatted String to String in C (not C++) Without Pointer Arithmetic?](//stackoverflow.com/q/2023947)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Append Formatted String to String in C (not C++) Without Pointer Arithmetic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023947/append-formatted-string-to-string-in-c-not-c-without-pointer-arithmetic)

Comment: Do `snprintf(full_message + strlen(full_message), sizeof(full_message) - strlen(full_message), " and %d", i);`. You can't do `sprintf(buf, "%s", buf)`, it's undefined behavior.

Comment: "So does that mean that strcat is off the table?" --> Write your own - it is a simple function.

Comment: Also if `full_message` isn't an array declare within the **current scope**, then `sizeof full_message` is actually `sizeof (a_pointer)` (8-bytes on x64_64, 4-bytes on x86, ...) [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is needed to help further.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would help ,you are overwriting `full_message` ,use `strcat` to append (or your own `strcat` function):

```
char* my_strcat(char* strg1, char* strg2)
{
    char* start = strg1;

    while (*strg1 != '\0')
    {
        strg1++;
    }

    while (*strg2 != '\0')
    {
        *strg1 = *strg2;
        strg1++;
        strg2++;
    }

    *strg1 = '\0';
    return start;
}
```

then call this function:

```
else
{
        sprintf(offset, " and %d", i);
        my_strcat(full_message, offset);

}
```

so you just have used `stdio.h` library functions.

Comment: What if I can't add strcat, as I'm only able to use stdio.h library?

Comment: @AerialSong I edited my post for your special case.